# Jquery - trying to select an image within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, parent-child, jquery-hover

I am new to jquery and am stuck trying to select an image inside a div.

```
<div class="div-main">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="description"></div>
  <img class="post-thumb" src="img.jpg"/>
</div>
```

I am trying to make the title and description show only when the the user hovers over the image in the div.

Currently I have it setup so that the animations happen when the div-main is hovered over

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".div-main").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).children(".title").fadeIn("slow");
        $(this).children(".description").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".div-main").css({ opacity: 0.1 });
        $(this).css({ opacity: 1.0 });
        $(this).show();
      }, 
      function () {
        $(".title").hide();
        $(".description").hide();
        $(".div-main").fadeIn("fast");
        $(".div-main").css({ opacity: 1.0 });
      }
    );

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ozowoy/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
$(".div-main").hover(
  function () {
    $(".title, .description", this).fadeTo(300, 1);
    $(".div-main").stop().fadeTo(0, 0.3);
    $(this).fadeTo(300,1);
  },function () {
    $(".title, .description").hide();
    $(".div-main").stop().fadeTo(300, 1);
  });
```

Comment: @crm remove .stop() and fast-hover multiple times the images, you'll see what will happend. `.stop()` is here to prevent animation buildups (clears the animation queue). Happy coding. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to post this as an answer.

```
$('.div-main > img')
    .hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".title, .description").fadeIn();  //Title & description
    },
    function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".title, .description").fadeOut();
    }
);
```

Comment: The OP wants the to make the title and description visible when hovering.  This doesn't do that.

Comment: @jfriend00 - The question is: `trying to select an image within a div`

Comment: The question states: `I am trying to make the title and description show only when the the user hovers over the image in the div.`

Comment: There is no item with an `id="title"` in their HTML. so `$("#title")` won't do anything.

Comment: That might work, but only if there is only one of these blocks of HTML in the entire page. This looks more like the type of HTML that would be repeated in which case you would be changing all titles and descriptions, not just the ones that were hovered.  See my answer for how to affect only the hovered ones.

Comment: @jfriend00 - See update again. It is correct now so you can revert the downvote. The downvote will mistake people that this answer is incorrect.

Comment: Still doesn't work because div-main is a class name, not an id value. Downvotes are probably because you made so many mistakes and needed someone else to point them all out to you.

Comment: @jfriend00 - The main point of the answer is not the `.` and `#`. It is the *concept*.

Comment: I can't believe you're complaining that people are pointing out errors in your solution.  Do you not want to offer something that would actually work?

Comment: I already did comment that Raminson's answer didn't do what the OP asked for 23 mins ago.

Answer (score 0):

To make the description and title fade in and out when you hover over the image, you could do this:

```
$('.div-main .post-thumb').hover(function(){
  $(this).parent().find(".title, .description").stop(true).fadeIn();
},
function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".title, .description").stop(true).fadeOut();
});
```

If the image is normally the only visible content except when hovering, then this might work better because things would remain visible when hovering over the title and description too:

```
$('.div-main').hover(function(){
  $(this).find(".title, .description").stop(true).fadeIn();
},
function() {
  $(this).find(".title, .description").stop(true).fadeOut();
});
```